# Which fonts can I use in wysiwyg on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-face

I have programmed javascript wysiwyg editor. User can change font of selected text with `select` tag. But when the user doesn't have a font from options there could be a problem.

I don't need some fancy fonts, so far I have these:

```
const FONTS = [
'Arial', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana', 'Georgia', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Arial Black', 'Impact', 'Lucida Console', 'Tahoma', 'Consolas', 'Helvetica', 'Courier New', 'Courier']
```

So I can't use css fallback. IMHO the best option would be to get fonts from some server, but I couldn't find fonts like Arial etc anywhere. What is the best way to be sure, that fonts would work? or are these fonts in `FONTS` save to use? (I don't need mobile support)

Comment: I haven't used a computer where Arial font was not present in a browser

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need some fancy font as fallback then why do you even care?
Default font will be used anyway which on depend on user operating system and their own preferences.

With that being said you can use fonts listed here as they are "safe" meaning they will always get rendered properly in every situation, browser, low connection etc...

List --> https://websitesetup.org/web-safe-fonts-html-css/

Comment: Because it is wysiwyg, so I don't want to give user an option 'Consolas' and after he switch to this option he will see Arial font. So I don't need fancy font. But I want to be sure, that these "normal" fonts will work on Windows, Mac and Linux, but hey, if there is no option to be sure.... And the closest thing to the guarantee is the list, that you sent, I can live with that. Just tell me, that there is no way to get all fonts in the list for free, place it on a server and give these fonts to the user and be sure, that it will always work and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Is your problem more of wp nature or actual css/html?